# My iPhone 4S running iOS 5.0.1 recently started showing "invalid sim" message

Tags: iphone, sim

I recently forgot to pay for my cellular service, and when I paid the service my iPhone keeps displaying an "Invalid sim" message, then I have to reboot to recover the service.

The phone is working correctly with internet access, calls and messages, the only problem is that I need to reboot the phone two or three times a day to eliminate the "invalid sim" message.

Comment: Have you removed and reinserted the SIM card at all? Sometimes this helps.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back. Reinserting the card did not help, but carrier offered to replace the card for free.  That fixed it. As already mentioned by Randolph, I have seen that (reinsertion) work in a few cases as well.

Comment: I have reinserted the SIM card two times and the problem persist, probably I will need to get a replacement SIM card from carrier will try that this weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem which has caused problems for a huge number of iPhone users, particularly outside traditional markets.

There is every reason to believe that it will be fixed by the imminent 5.1 iOS release.

It appears to have something to do with carrier settings, GSM frequencies, and/or SIM cards.

There is some detail in this thread ...
https://discussions.apple.com/message/17769511?ac_cid=142432#17769511

If it is not fixed in the 5.1 release, there will be a lot of very angry iPhone 4S users!

Comment: it appears that the upgrade fixed the problem for me so far :)